# How to setup tramp mode through a linux gateway and hardware authentication?

Tags: tramp, ssh

I don't have direct access to my remote machine at work. 
Normally I login with the following commands

```
(local)$ ssh id@gateway 
Yubikey prompt (physically push a button on the yubikey)
PW prompt:
(gateway)$ (custom login command) 
PW prompt: 
(gateway)$ rlogin id@remote
(remote)$ access!
```

I've gone through the tramp examples for multi-hop ssh connections. however

1. There were no mention of how to setup tramp with a physical
   authentication device
2. No mention of how to issue a command on the
   gateway

Is there a way to tunnel through this in tramp-mode?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which Tramp version you are using. The recent Tramp 2.4.0 manual discusses the case in section [6.9.1 Tunneling with ssh](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Firewalls). As `ProxyCommand` you need to apply your `rlogin id@remote`.